# How to use a variable in different classes without it changing

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, automation, automated-tests

Im trying to use a variable the i have taken in one class and then use that variable in a different classes.
So this is my code and it basically takes an id from a url

```
public class GameId {

    public String game_id() {

        String currentURL = Drivers.getDriver().getCurrentUrl();
        String[] arrayURL = currentURL.split("/");
        int arrLength = arrayURL.length;
        final String gameID;
        gameID = arrayURL[arrLength - 1];
        System.out.println(gameID);
        return gameID;

    }
}
```

Im trying to use this in my tests in a different class but it doesn't give me the same answer, im trying to assert that this game id is included in the url on a different page but the function is running again so the value changes.

```
public void guest_login_from_pick_screen(){

    GameId gameid = new GameId();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Drivers.getDriver(), 10);
    gameid.game_id();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlMatches("https://web-game-stage.sportdec.com/games/"+ gameid.game_id()+"/join/"));

}
```

I use both of these functions in my test but i want the value of the first instance (gameid.game_id();) to be used in the second instance (fixscreen.guest_login_from_pick_screen();). Here is the full code

```
@Test
public void join_game_already_logged_in () throws Exception {

    Header header = new Header();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    GameLobby gamelobby = new GameLobby();


    gamelobby.clickElementWithName("Test Game");

    gamelobby.select_game();


    LeaderBoard leaderboard = new LeaderBoard();
    GameId gameid = new GameId();
    gameid.game_id();
    leaderboard.numberOfUsers();
    leaderboard.joinGame();
    FixturesScreen fixscreen = new FixturesScreen();
    fixscreen.guest_login_from_pick_screen();
    fixscreen.four_picks_make();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    fixscreen.picks_match_total();
    fixscreen.submit_picks();
    Login login = new Login();
    login.select_register_from_login();

    Register register = new Register();
    register.register_in_pick_screen();
    fixscreen.submit_picks();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    PickReceipt pickReceipt = new PickReceipt();
    pickReceipt.your_in_the_game();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your GameID class as singleton class and need to use encapsulation concept.So, that it will create a single instance and you can get the currentgame Id as below

You have to change your GameID as below

```
public class GameId {
    private String currentGameId;
    private static GameId gameID;

    public static GameId getInstance(){
        if(gameID==null){
            gameID=new GameId();
        }
        return gameID;
    }

    public void setCurrentGameId(String id){
        currentGameId=id;
    }

    public String getCurrentGameId(){
        return currentGameId;
    }

    public void game_id() {
        String currentURL = Drivers.getDriver().getCurrentUrl();
        String[] arrayURL = currentURL.split("/");
        int arrLength = arrayURL.length;
        final String gameID;
        gameID = arrayURL[arrLength - 1];
        System.out.println(gameID);
        this.currentGameId=gameID;

    }
}
```

You can get the current CaseID by simply calling `getCurrentGameId` method.

```
public void guest_login_from_pick_screen(){

    GameId gameid =GameId.getInstance();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Drivers.getDriver(), 10);
    //gameid.currentGameId();//It will give the current CaseID from the GameID class
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlMatches("https://web-game-stage.sportdec.com/games/"+gameid.getCurrentGameId()+"/join/"));
}
```

In your test method, it should be modified as below

```
LeaderBoard leaderboard = new LeaderBoard();
GameId gameid = GameId.getInstance(); //It will create a new instance
gameid.game_id();//This method will be executed once and gameID will be updated in a variable called currentGameId.So, we can simply call the getCurrentGameId() method to get the current ID.
```

Comment: Ah i kind of get it, but when i added this i keep getting a cannot resolve method "getInstance"

Comment: private GameId gameID; needs to be changed as private static GameId gameID; in GameId class

Comment: Ive changed it but the getInstance is still red and saying cannot resolve instance, it still looks like the value will be replaced in the method later on in the test?

Comment: I have updated the answer by changing the getInstance method as static and changed the gameid object creation as GameId gameid = GameId.getInstance()

Comment: Cool that looks good but the gameid.currentGameId has private access so is unusable in the guest_login_from_pick_screen method. Can i just change that to public??

Comment: variable is declared as private and method is created as public .So, you can simply call the gameid .getCurrentGameId() method in your case

Answer (score 0):

please use the below code :-

```
public void guest_login_from_pick_screen(){

    GameId gameid = new GameId();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Drivers.getDriver(), 10);
    String var = gameid.game_id();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlMatches("https://web-game-stage.sportdec.com/games/"+ var +"/join/"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make variable `static` as follows:

```
public static String url="www.example.com";
```

and then it can be used wherever you want.

Comment: I understand that, but when the method runs again in fixscreen.guest_login_from_pick_screen(); the variable is replaced, im trying to use the first variable i got from gameid.game_id(); im basically trying to store the first variable to use later on

Comment: when method run again then it will change the value , we have declared it static not final
you can change the value easily in other class 1.e url="abc.com";

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GameId {

    public static String gameId = "";
    public String game_id() {

        String currentURL = Drivers.getDriver().getCurrentUrl();
        String[] arrayURL = currentURL.split("/");
        int arrLength = arrayURL.length;
        final String gameID;
        gameID = arrayURL[arrLength - 1];
        System.out.println(gameID);
        gameId  = gameID;
        return gameID;

    }
}
```

Create GameId object at once and then from next time use like this GameId.gameId